# VB.net soap client not working on PHP soap server

Tags: php, vb.net, soap, nusoap

I wrote a soap service in PHP using nusoap. It works fine with the test client I wrote in PHP, however, our customer wrote his client in vb.net and it is not working. There are no errors that I see, but the service is not parsing his requests properly.

I am letting nusoap generate the WSDL, and it looks fine. If I compare a message that I send in to one of his messages, I do see a few differences in the envelope, but I'm not sure if the problem is on my end or his.

Here are the good and bad responses.

Good :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
    SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">

  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns6361:uploadDocument xmlns:ns6361="http://tempuri.org">
      <__numeric_0>
        <firmCode xsi:type="xsd:string">999*site1</firmCode>
        <docID xsi:type="xsd:string">id</docID>
        <docType xsi:type="xsd:string">tif</docType>
        <document xsi:type="xsd:string">SUkqAMpDAAAmoFy..lots of data omitted here</document>
        </__numeric_0>
      </ns6361:uploadDocument>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
  </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Bad:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    xmlns:tns="http://www.inassist.com/docupload" 
    xmlns:types="http://www.inassist.com/docupload/encodedTypes" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <soap:Body soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <q1:uploadDocument xmlns:q1="urn:server">
      <firmCode xsi:type="xsd:string">999*site1</firmCode>
      <docID xsi:type="xsd:string">0000007126</docID>
      <docType xsi:type="xsd:string">PDF</docType>
      <document xsi:type="xsd:base64Binary">JVBERi0xLj..data omitted...</document>
    </q1>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to me that the biggest problem is going to be the `<__numeric_0>` tag in the good response.

If you can modify your end to eliminate the need for this tag, then the only other possible problem looks like the namespace for the `uploadDocument`, which is `q1` in the bad response and `ns6361` in the good document.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Let me look into that. The <_numeric_0> tag was automatically created by nusoap, but I will see what tweaks I can make. Thank you.